A confusion about linear trasformation in ahlfors' complex book page 84
He wrote that "If two circles are tangent to each other, their orientations can be compared. Indeed, we can use a linear transformation which throws their common point to oo. The circles become parallel straight lines"
How would this work, is there a way to visualize this with an example?

By "linear" Ahlfors means "linear-fractional". If two circles are tangent at $a\in \mathbb C$, you can use the map $f(z)=1/(z-a)$. However, I do not know what he means by "can be compared" and why would he need to map the point of tangency to infinity in order to do the "comparison."

He's talking about a Möbius transformation,  aka linear fractional transformation.
They're of the form $f(z)=\frac {az+b}{cz+d}, ad-bc\neq0.$
They take generalized circles to generalized circles.
Look at the circle $\mid z\mid=1.$  Define $f(z)=\frac {z+1}{z-1}.$  Then $-1,i,1$ go to $0,-i,\infty,$ respectively. So the circle goes to the $y$-axis.
Now I leave it for you to check what happens to the circle $\mid z-2\mid=1,$ which happens to be tangent to the first circle at $1.$

Yeah,it goes to the line x=2.This example suffices as the clarification of the visualization.

Yeah,  I don't have my copy of Ahlfor's, but, by going say counter clockwise on both circles, and comparing directions on the lines, I suspect that you can compare orientations.
